# How do we find the width of scroll bar?

Tags: javascript

Do you know any cross-browser methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.scrollBarWidth = function() { 
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';  
  var width = document.body.clientWidth; 
  document.body.style.overflow = 'scroll';  
  width -= document.body.clientWidth;  
  if(!width) width = document.body.offsetWidth - document.body.clientWidth; 
  document.body.style.overflow = '';  
  return width;  
}
```

Comment: Does that work well crossbrowser? Under what browser has this code been tested?

Answer (score 2):

There aren't any way working cross browser (IE is the problem, as always), sorry

Comment: I do not believe there is no way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in MooTools, and I just finished full cross-browser testing.

http://jsfiddle.net/jP6q2/2/

Long story short:

```
var body = $$('body')[0];

var test = new Element('div', {'style':'visibility:hidden; width: 100px; height: 100px; overflow: scroll;'});

test.inject(body);

var scrollbar = {
    width: test.offsetWidth - test.scrollWidth
    , height: test.offsetHeight - test.scrollHeight
}

test.dispose();
```